# Yaml: DateTime Day - 1

Tags: c#, yaml

I'm very new to Yaml. Watched a few tuts on it. I'm trying to get a datetime - 1 day.

Here is my current code:

```
 fromDate: "{{ func:date_format(func:current_datetime().AddDays(-1), 'yyyy/MM/dd') }}"
```

In .Net we can use the .addDays but I don't think that works in Yaml. Just not sure how to do it in Yaml. Thanks in advance. If you have links to Yaml syntax that would be great btw.